# Google maps search to get lots of results at once

Tags: google-maps, search, iframe, google-maps-markers, google-places

I want to know if there's any way to get my map to show many search results like this one on their http://maps.google.com.

For example, if I search for "restaurants japan", I would like my map to show it like this screenshot.
=> http://i3.minus.com/iGzzuu1bBHgNJ.png

The closest approach I found is `Google Places Search`, but they say it can return only 60 results at most. This would not be enough for me.

Since I need to add a load of custom markers after the searching, I don't think `<iframe>` embedding couldn't help me here. Am I right?

Also, if I need it to show only red dots (remove those (A-xx) pins), how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A [Radar Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) will return up to 200 results (but with less detail and for more "cost")

[reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RadarSearchRequest)